# SQL Query to Get list of all users along with their blogs

Tags: multisite, mysql

How to query for a list of users along with the blogs in which they are member of in a multi site wordpress installation.

For example, I need the results as below

```
user domain
abc  xyz.com
abc  example.com
ggh  example.com
```

I tried the below query, but its not listing all the domains..

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_login, a.user_email, c.domain
FROM wp_users a
JOIN wp_usermeta b ON a.id = b.user_id
JOIN wp_blogs c ON b.meta_value = c.site_id
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

I am not sure how the network/multi site works.. can anyone please tell me how to get the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`get_blogs_of_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blogs_of_user) to get all the blogs of a given user.

So to get a list sorted by the users:

```
global $wpdb;
$blogs = array();
$user_ids = $wpdb->get_col( 'SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users' );
foreach( $user_ids as $user_id ) {
    $blogs[$user_id] = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id );
}
// you can use var_dump( $blogs ); to see what's in the $blogs array
```

Comment: can you please give me a direct sql query, that would be very helpful..

Comment: and how should i use this code?

Answer (score 4):

Needing the same thing, I managed to find the key data in the wp_usermeta tables.  This worked for me:

```
SELECT u.user_login, b.domain,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(um.meta_value,'"', 2), '"', -1) as role
FROM wp_users u
JOIN wp_usermeta um ON u.ID = um.user_id
JOIN wp_blogs b ON b.blog_id = SUBSTRING(um.meta_key, 4, LENGTH(um.meta_key)-16)
WHERE um.meta_key LIKE 'wp_%_capabilities'
```

Results:

```
user_login    domain       role
============  ============ ================
webmaster     blog1.com    administrator
user          blog1.com    editor
webmaster     blog2.com    administrator
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't leave a comment but the response from Wraezor Sharp worked pretty well for me. I needed user email addresses, our multisite instance was all on the same domain name, and I only wanted admins and not subscribers. This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
  u.user_login
  , u.user_email
  , concat('https://', b.domain, b.path) as site
  , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(um.meta_value,'"', 2), '"', -1) as role
FROM
  wp_users u
  JOIN wp_usermeta um ON u.ID = um.user_id
  JOIN wp_blogs b ON b.blog_id = SUBSTRING(um.meta_key, 4, LENGTH(um.meta_key)-16)
WHERE
  um.meta_key LIKE 'wp_%_capabilities'
  AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(um.meta_value,'"', 2), '"', -1) IN ('administrator', 'editor')
ORDER BY
  site asc
;
```