# How to search users globally on a multisite install?

Tags: multisite, users

I'm using the REST API to create/update/delete users on a multisite install in order to sync data with a 3rd party resource. When I am checking whether to update or create a user, I'm using the `search` parameter to search on usernames, which works fine on a single site, but if a user exists in the system on a different site, how can I tell beyond trying the insert, which triggers a *Username is already in use* error? I've found [this](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/02/08/improving-the-rest-api-users-endpoint-for-multisite-in-4-7-3-and-4-8/) proposed change, which looks to be exactly what I need, but it hasn't made it into code yet. How can I achieve this? I don't mind writing a custom endpoint and doing it in PHP, but I can't find any functions that allows searching globally for users. Even `WP_User_Query` [appears](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/) limited to one blog at a time.

Comment: This is the closest solution I've found so far: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127081/sql-query-to-get-list-of-all-users-along-with-their-blogs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you can do this using a `blog_id` of `0`:

```
$args = array( 'blog_id' => 0 );
$users = get_users( $args );
var_dump( $users );
```

If you want to search for a specific user, the process is similar:

```
$args = array( 'blog_id' => 0, 'search' => '{username to search for}' );
$users = get_users( $args );
var_dump( $users );
```

I discovered this while poking around in [the `wp-cli` source code](https://github.com/wp-cli/entity-command/blob/master/src/User_Command.php#L129) (since I knew that `wp user list --network` would return a list of all the users on a Multisite network). It's corroborated by a [user comment on the `WP_User_Query::prepare_query()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/#comment-2248).

Comment: Re-reading your question, I'm not sure this will help with REST API user searching on a remote WP installation.

Comment: Maybe not with the out-of-the-box REST API, but this seems like a cleaner way to handle the problem without resorting to WP_Query directly. This could be easily added via a custom endpoint in a simple plugin or `functions.php` so I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer.